# VBA not calculating before save

Tags: vba, excel, calculation

I have a pretty basic VBA script that saves a copy of my report, refreshes my SQL data connections, adjusts column width and resaves the file. For some reason, none of the options I found are adequately pausing to calculate before the file is saved.

```
Sub SaveAs()
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Dep - " & _
        Format(Date, "YYYYMMDD") & ".xlsm" _

    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

    Columns("B:N").Select
    Range("B37").Activate
    Columns("B:N").EntireColumn.AutoFit

    Application.Calculate

    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub

Sub Button()
    Call SaveAs 'Macro1
End Sub
```

I have tried several options to delay it, but none seems to work

```
'Option 1
Application.Calculate
Application.Calculation = xlManual
Application.CalculateBeforeSave = True

'Option 2
Do While Application.CalculationState <> xlDone
    Application.Calculate
    Loop

'Option 3
Application.Calculate
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:30")

'Option 4
Application.Calculate
If Application.CalculationState = xlDone Then
    DoEvents
End If

ActiveWorkbook.Save
```

Any idea what I am missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example of a formula or function that's not calculating?

Comment: I have SQL data pulled into tables, and then on separate worksheet contains a series of SUMIFS formulas.

    =SUMIFS('ADB Data'!$C:$C,'ADB Data'!$A:$A,'DoD Bal'!$C5,'ADB Data'!$B:$B,'DoD Bal'!D$2)

Comment: Are you saying that the SQL data isn't updating? (If so, that's not a calculation issue.) If not, what happens if you click on a cell with a formula, and then click in the formula bar, and then hit ENTER?  (Does the cell calculate?) Also does the bottom left of your screen say "Calculate"?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the script with F8? Doing it that way, how long does it take to calculate?

Comment: The SQL data is pulling correctly, and if I manually save the file, the formulas will recalculate before the file is saved. But when I try to use the VBA script, I get a pop up from Excel that states "This will cancel a pending data refresh. Continue?".

So the SQL data connection completes before the next step, but the Excel formulas are not alloted enough time to complete before saving. The odd part is it only should need a few seconds. I tried adding a 30 second wait, and that didnt help.

Comment: Robby, it's instantaneous.

Comment: Are your SQL connections set as backgroundrefresh=true ?  If Yes then your code will not wait until they're done.

Comment: Tim, I dont think that's the issue, since the SQL connections are completing. It's the excel formulas that reference other cells that are not completing.